# Problems with a lithium battery

Tags: electricity

I have a lithium battery that is separated from any device and is producing a whitish-gray smoke every time the wires move. Sometimes it makes hissing noises.

Is there a way to solve these problems?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Take the [tour] to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) using $\LaTeX$ syntax. It seems to me that this battery is broken and should be disposed of in a secure manner. Other than that I cannot see how this question relates to chemistry, so it might get closed as off topic.

Comment: It may be a side reaction or short circuit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to drain its charge and put it into recycling.  It's probably a fire hazard at this point, and the damage that a fire from it could cause will cost more than a new one.